# FFmpeg command to record Skype sound and video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to record my Skype calls using `ffmpeg`. I need to record audio *(pulseaudio)* & video *(X)*. But it seems that it is a bit tricky...

For audio recording I want to use my Scarlet 2i4 audio interface that is listed as device number `10` in pulseaudio:

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:~$ pactl list short cards
2   alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0  module-alsa-card.c
10  alsa_card.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00 module-alsa-card.c

~$ pactl list short sinks
16  alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-surround-40    module-alsa-card.c  s32le 4ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED

~$ pactl list short sources
24  alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-surround-40.monitor    module-alsa-card.c  s32le 4ch 44100HzSUSPENDED
25  alsa_input.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s32le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

From this I can see that my desired card is a device `10` so I structured my ffmpeg command like this:

```
ffmpeg \
-f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -probesize 17M -r 30 -i :0.0+0+0 \
-f pulse -ac 2 -device 10 \
-output.mkv
```

where:

- **2nd** line specifies all **video input parameters** *(tested & working)*
- **3rd** line specifies all **audio parameters** *(not working)*

But when I execute the command I get error:

```
Output #0, pulse, to 'output.mkv':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Does anyone have any idea why? How can I record Skype sound?

---

### ADD

@Gyan's suggestion although did not work it pointed me to the right direction.

I used parameter `-device` instead of `-i`. The later is an **input** parameter and if we specify a **device number** `10` it does not work. We have to specify an input that we can get using `pactl list short sources`. So we can use **source number** `25` e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -probesize 17M -r 30 -i :0.0+0+0 -f pulse -ac 2 -i 25 output.mkv
```

This runs but it only records one source which is my microphone. It completely ignores e.g Skype, audio player...

If I open `pavucontrol` when running Skype and my audio player, `pavucontroll` shows me these application streams:

[image]

How do I include *"Skype"* and *"Deadbeef"* streams into the recording?

Comment: See [Capturing ONLY desktop audio with ffmpeg](https://askubuntu.com/a/682793/)

Comment: @llogan. The suggested link shows, how to record desktop sounds i.e. music player & Skype, but microphone is ignored. I need a solution to record both - desktop sounds and microphone.

Comment: Perhaps you can add the mic as another input and optionally mix with amix or amerge.

Comment: @llogan I searched for amix and amerge in the Debian repositoories and I could not find those. Could you write an answer on how to do this?

Comment: I also set my input/outpit inside Skype to "default" (same as with parameter `-i default`). I don't know if this will help...

Comment: These are [ffmpeg filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html). Many examples on SU/SO. Search `[ffmpeg] is:answer amix`.

Comment: Ok, this looks like a vast topic. I have studying to do... I will respond once I know my stuff around filters. Thank you for now.

Comment: I found out that also I should not choose source `24` as it is a `.monitor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pulse input still needs a `-i` option with an arg for ffmpeg to mark it as an input. A quick glance through the code suggests changing the 3rd line to below should work

```
-f pulse -ac 2 -i 10
```

Comment: Your suggestion failed with an error `10: Input/output error`. The reason was that I was not supposed to specify a `card` number `10` (!), but `source` number `25`. If I use this command ffmpeg starts and runs: `ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -probesize 17M -r 30 -i :0.0+0+0 -f pulse -ac 2 -i 25 output.mkv`. But it completely ignores Skype and my audio player while microphone is recorded fine. Should I add an application streams to the recording? How? I added this in the ADD section of the updated question. Please take a look.

Comment: This helps me to start recording, but I also need to learn ffmpeg mixers as @llogan suggested...